# DHTMLX Scheduler Custom button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using DHTMLX scheduler in my MVC application. In that window event popup I am adding the custom button named as 'Reminder'. My problem is while clicking the reminder button I need to display another div which is the same concept implement in the repeat event of the scheduler.

If the  disabled button is clicked it will show the div with corresponding elements. I need to set the div custom.

[image]

I need to write the code for reminder button manually.

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question? What code do you have already to start on the problem?

Comment: OK. Are you using any libraries, like jQuery? I don't know if the asp.net has its own JS libraries. Do you know which files to edit to attach DOM events to things - in your case a `click` event to the Reminder button?

Comment: Now i displayed the div while clicking a button. On clicking a button i used toggle to show the div. Now my problem is inside the div i need to display another form or div. Is it possible? Please help its urgent. Thanks..

Comment: If you have some JavaScript code for this already, please add it to your question. (I don't recommend asking for urgency, either in questions or comments: helpers are volunteers who answer for fun in their free time, and they will answer at their leisure - thanks!).

Comment: ok. thanks for ur help